# Custom tab style in android

Tags: android

I want to add custom style to my tabs.I am using following code for add tab:

```
ActionBar.Tab tab1=actionBar.newTab();

tab1.setTabListener(this);
tab1.setCustomView(R.layout.tab_style);
TextView txt1 = (TextView)tab1.getCustomView().findViewById(R.id.tabtext);
txt1.setText(R.string.tab_1);
actionBar.addTab(tab1);
```

tab_style.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/tabtext"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="6dip"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
/>
```

I want to change tab background.How can I do this ?

Answer (score 0):

```
  public static void setTabColor(TabHost tabhost) {
for(int i=0;i<tabhost.getTabWidget().getChildCount();i++) {
    tabhost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FF0000")); //unselected
}
tabhost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(tabhost.getCurrentTab()).setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#0000FF")); // selected
 }
```

Comment: What is the tabhost ?